# Difference between geometry.area() and ee.Image.pixelArea().reduceRegion(geometry)

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have been working with Google Earth Engine (GEE) and I encountered an unexpected discrepancy in the output when calculating the area of a geometry using different methods. Specifically, I noticed that the `featureCollection.geometry().area()` function and the `ee.Image.pixelArea().reduce(geometry)` operation yield different results.

To provide some context, I have a FeatureCollection in GEE that contains several features with geometries representing different regions of interest. My goal is to compute the area of these geometries accurately. Initially, I used the `featureCollection.geometry().area()` method, which is commonly used to calculate the area of a geometry directly from a FeatureCollection object.

However, I noticed that the results obtained from this method differed from the ones obtained by utilizing the `ee.Image.pixelArea().reduce(geometry)` operation. This operation involves creating an ee.Image object and then applying the reduce() function on the geometry of interest.

I would like to understand why these two methods produce inconsistent results. Is there a fundamental difference in how these functions calculate the area? Could it be related to the spatial resolution of the imagery used in ee.Image.pixelArea()? How can I obtain accurate area calculations?

Here is a simplified code snippet demonstrating the issue:

```
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection("your/feature/collection");

// Method 1: Calculating area using featureCollection.geometry().area()
var areaMethod1 = fc.geometry().area();

// Method 2: Calculating area using ee.Image.pixelArea().reduce(geometry)
var areaMethod2 = ee.Image.pixelArea().reduceRegion({
  geometry: geomFeature.geometry(),
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  scale: 30
})

print('Area (Method 1):', areaMethod1);
print('Area (Method 2):', areaMethod2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the fundamental difference is that when a polygon is rasterized then the original geometry gets lost.

The ee.Image.pixelArea() gives a sum of the area of the pixels but they can never present the vector geometry exactly. The difference gets smaller with smaller pixels size. See this image with a triangle and a rasterized version of it.

[image]

Comment: do you mean the green triangle is what we get from `fc.geometry().area()` and the grey one from the `reduceRegion()` approach?

Comment: Yes, pixelArea is summing the areas of the grey squeres=pixels.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and I'm at a loss as to what should be a accepted difference. Here I calculated the area of a "square" using `geometry().area()` and `reduceRegion()` and I'm getting 0.4% difference in the result. Is that expected / accepted?
https://code.earthengine.google.com/0c88507541891fc8858c52b0a0f33101